# Not able to redirect when model state is false, Showing some page not found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-view

I'm trying to create a Strongly typed login page, when the login page loads and if i try to get some validation on clicking login button it is showing some Error message.

```
public class LoginDetails
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name ="Email Id")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="PassWord")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Remember Me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

public ActionResult Login(LoginDetails model) 
{
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
 }

    return View(model); //Error Occurs Here
}
```

Showing Error Like Below

> Server Error in '/' Application. The view 'Login' or its master was
>   not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The
>   following locations were searched:
>
> ```
> ~/Views/Login/Login.aspx
> ~/Views/Login/Login.ascx
> ~/Views/Shared/Login.aspx
> ~/Views/Shared/Login.ascx
> ~/Views/Login/Login.cshtml
> ~/Views/Login/Login.vbhtml
> ~/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
> ~/Views/Shared/Login.vbhtml
> ```

Comment: Make sure that you have view page named "Login" and default view engine recognizes it, otherwise you need to create custom view engine configuration.

Comment: Check your `Views` folder! Is there any folder name as like as your controller name and then a view name called `login.cshtml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default conventions to ASP.NET MVC, if you don't specify the view name while returning from an action method, it considers the view path to be :

> ~ [**Views Directory**] **/** [**Directory with same name as the calling Controller**] **/** [**View with same name as
>   Action with extension (.aspx, .ascx, .cshtml, .vbhtml)**]

If not found, it also searches the view in shared directory also:

> ~ [**Views Directory**] **/** [**Shared Directory**] **/** [**View with same name as
>   Action with extension (.aspx, .ascx, .cshtml, .vbhtml)**]

In your case, the `Login View` is not found in any of the above directories, hence the error. Try to provide the full path of the view to fix the issue as:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginDetails model) 
{
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
 }

    //Pass the full view path
    return View("~/Views/[Directory in which the view is created]/Login.cshtml", model);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend explicitly type view name or path to view, so there is no confusion

```
return View(model,"Viewname or PathToView");
```